# How to set the size of tk_messageBox?

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit, tkmessagebox, messagedialog

I am using a `tk_messageBox` with a lage message, so I would like to configure the layout of that message dialog.

I am using `tk_messageBox` like this:

```
set status [tk_messageBox -type yesno -icon warning -message "Here goes a text with 50 words"]
```

How can I set the width and height of `tk_messageBox` here?

Maybe there are some better alternatives for `tk_messageBox`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't set the size of a `tk_messageBox` (that's functionality which doesn't fit with the way those dialogs work on Windows and OSX). You *can* try putting some of the message into the `-detail` option, which usually uses a smaller font.

Or you can try looking in the file `msgbox.tcl` of your Tk installation for the Tcl code that implements the message box dialog on Unix/X11. Hint: on that platform *only*, `tk_messageBox` is really an alias for `::tk::MessageBox`. The name of the widget created by that script depends on the `-parent` option, but if that's absent, it's `.__tk__messagebox`. Knowing that, you should be able to use clever event handling to configure the `toplevel` widget in question. But this is not a nice solution, and won't work on either Windows or OSX (when build for Aqua instead of X11).

Answer (score 3):

Is this what you had in mind?

```
import Tkinter
import tkMessageBox 

window = Tkinter.Tk()
window.option_add('*Dialog.msg.width', 50)
tkMessageBox.showinfo("header", "Hello, World!")
```

Comment: Who was talking about Python here? Please stick to Tcl/Tk when the question is about Tcl/Tk. Thanks!

Comment: This seems to make the box wider, but the text doesn't flow out into the new space. Any idea how to fix that?

Comment: Same here; it makes it wider but doesn't allow the text to fill that extra space. How do we fix that?

Answer (score 1):

`.option_add` may only work for linux operating systems, but you can control font, where the lines wrap, and the width of the box:

```
root.option_add('*Dialog.msg.font', 'Helvetica 24')
root.master.option_add('*Dialog.msg.width', 34)
root.master.option_add("*Dialog.msg.wrapLength", "6i")
```

(where "6i" is the length of the line in inches)

Answer (score 0):

I use these settings, but haven't tested on other platforms beside X11

```
option add *Dialog.msg.wrapLength 10c 
option add *Dialog.dtl.wrapLength 10c
```

Of course you can try other sizes than 10c (which stands for 10 centimeters).